# Using std::size from non-const context

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I'm wondering why constexpr functions (std::size in particular) do not work from some non-const context when only type matters.

Let's have a look at two array_size implementations:

1. The old good c++98

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (&array_size_helper(const T (&)[N]))[N];
#define array_size(a)  sizeof(array_size_helper(a))
```

2. Since C++11 you can use constexpr (the following is `std::size` implementation from GCC-8)

```
constexpr size_t size(const _Tp (&/*__array*/)[_Nm]) noexcept { return _Nm; }
```

The second version is nice and perfect except it does not work the same way as the first one does. Since first macro is related on `sizeof` it only cares about types, while `constexpr` function is much complicated matter.

Consider an example:

```
struct A
{
    int a[10];
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
char (&array_size_helper(const T (&)[N]))[N];

# define array_size(a)  sizeof(array_size_helper(a))

int main()
{
    A a;
    A* new_A = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&a);
    static_assert(array_size(a.a) == 10) // OK;
    static_assert(array_size(new_A->a) == 10); //OK
    static_assert(std::size(a.a) == 10); //OK
    static_assert(std::size(new_A->a) == 10); //error: the value of ‘new_A’ is not usable in a constant expression
}
```

Why is that? Why does `std::size` care about anything but type? Shouldn't it be re-implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [whole blog post](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/) about this. No, `std::size` shouldn't be reimplemented.

There's an important difference between the two implementations: with `array_size()`, everything is in an unevaluated context. Only the types matter, not any of the specific values. `array_size()` works for any C array type and for no other types.

`std::size()` on the other hand works on all ranges. But it *has* to evaluate it's arguments. And when we're doing constant evaluation, there's a strict set of rules we have to follow. One such is that undefined behavior is ill-formed - the compiler must track each and every such access. So when you read through a pointer or reference, the compiler must verify that that read is valid. It's facially weird that `std::size(a.a)` works but `std::size(new_A->a)` does not, but consider the differing operations that have to happen in these two cases:

- for `std::size(a.a)`, we don't ever have to look at `a`. The member access is just some offset. We bind a reference to that (the parameter of `std::size`) but the implementation of `size()` never actually reads that reference. So even though `a` itself isn't *readable* in a constant expression, we're not actually doing any reading of it - so this just works.
- for `std::size(new_A->a)`, the very first thing we have to do is read the value of `new_A` in order to perform that dereference. But `new_A` isn't a constant, so we can't read its value during constant evaluation, so we're already done. It doesn't matter that we don't even need the value that we're reading at, we just care about its type in this situation.

This is a fundamental limitation at the moment - in that statically sized ranges you need a type trait (or macro) to get their size as constant expressions, while dynamically sized ranges you need to rely on `std::size()`.